# How do I completely reset and delete all Music.app settings and configurations

Tags: macos, itunes, catalina, music

I was looking for a way to get a completely clean slate on the Music.app in macOS Catalina.

I attempted to find and delete all related settings in `~/Library`, `~/Library/Cache`, `~/Library/Preferences`, and removed the Music folder from `~/Music`.

However, every time I start up the `Music.app` after this, the old song list information is still there, but obviously, the music files cannot be found since I deleted them. (I get the fist time welcome popups such though.)

Are there any other files, databases, etc, that need to be cleared out before I'll get a completely clean slate again?

EDIT:
I used this script to try and clear files:

I tried this to get rid of the files but it didn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Library/
music=$(find . -iname "*com.apple.music*" 2>/dev/null)
itunes=$(find . -iname "*itunes*" 2>/dev/null)
IFS=$'\n'
for x in $music; do rm -r "$x"; done
for x in $itunes; do rm -r "$x"; done
```

Comment: You didn't say what you deleted so we can't tell if you missed one, that said, what about old iTunes preferences? I would think that if music.app can't find it's own preferences it would use old iTunes preferences thinking it was an upgrade situation. So look for iTunes preferences too.

Comment: edited the question with the bash script commands that I used to get rid of all the files

Comment: Not being a unix-y script guy I can't tell if that also deleted folders, it doesn't seem like it and there are folders like ~/Library/iTunes. You may want to scan through the ~/Library folder using the old $EYE and delete anything that doesn't match your pattern as well.

Answer (score 4):

I attempted to delete the Music library from ~/Music, but Music seemed to want to rebuild that, and discovered that downloaded music and other things were missing which lead to some issues.

I decided to delete the Library from ~/Music and when launching Music, hold the option key until you are be prompted to open or create a new Library, select to create the Library and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 4):

I managed to successfully reset everything by using AppCleaner and dragging Music.app into it (doesn’t show up in AppCleaner search because it’s a system app)

It found a couple folders, including (but not limited to):

- `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Music`
- `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Music.*`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Music.*`
- `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Music.*`

I also deleted `~/Music/Music`